# Getting urecognized field error message when parsing csv

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to convert CSV file to JSON using Jackson library. I have created the POJO class attributes similar to CSV file headers. But even though facing **unrecognized field error problem**.

Here is my code

```
    public static List<SalesValidationDetails> parseCSVFile(File file) throws IOException {
                
          CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
          MappingIterator<SalesValidationDetails> eachSale = 
          csvMapper.readerWithTypedSchemaFor(SalesValidationDetails.class).readValues(file);
    return eachSale.readAll();

}
```

Pojo class:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "OrderReference", "Date", "Status", "StatusNote", "NewSalePrice", "TransactionPartsNew", "Currency"})
public class SalesValidationDetails {

    private String OrderReference;
    private String Date;
    private String Status;
    private String StatusNote;
    private String NewSalePrice;
    private String TransactionPartsNew;
    private String Currency;
    
    public String getOrderReference() {
    return OrderReference;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return Status;
}

public String getStatusNote() {
    return StatusNote;
}

public String getNewSalePrice() {
    return NewSalePrice;
}

public String getTransactionPartNew() {
    return TransactionPartsNew;
}

public String getCurrency() {
    return Currency;
}

public void setOrderReference(String OrderReference) {
    OrderReference = OrderReference;
}

public void setDate(String Date) {
    Date = Date;
}

public void setStatus(String Status) {
    Status = Status;
}

public void setStatusNote(String StatusNote) {
    StatusNote = StatusNote;
}

public void setNewSalePrice(String NewSalePrice) {
    NewSalePrice = NewSalePrice;
}

public void setTransactionPartsNew(String TransactionPartsNew) {
    TransactionPartsNew = TransactionPartsNew;
}

public void setCurrency(String Currency) {
    Currency = Currency;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SalesValidationDetails{" +
            "orderReference='" + OrderReference + '\'' +
            ", date=" + Date +
            ", status='" + Status + '\'' +
            ", statusNote='" + StatusNote + '\'' +
            ", newSalesPrice='" + NewSalePrice + '\'' +
            ", transactionPartsNew='" + TransactionPartsNew + '\'' +
            ", currency='" + Currency + '\'' +
            '}';
}

}
```

My CSV file looks like this:
[image]

My error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "transactionPartNew" (class com.decathlon.beans.SalesValidationDetails), not marked as ignorable (7 known properties: "currency", "newSalePrice", "statusNote", "orderReference", "date", "status", "transactionPartsNew"])
 at [Source: (com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.UTF8Reader); line: 1, column: 94] (through reference chain: com.decathlon.beans.SalesValidationDetails["transactionPartNew"])
```

Can somebody help me what is wrong here, i have tried all the ways.

Comment: I can see that “TransactionPartsNew” in CSV has a space or tab in the column name. Is it typo. If so, could you please try to delete the space and try again.

Comment: @AlexanderMakarov, sorry it was a mistake when writing the question. Actually there is no space in header.

Comment: May I know if you have public getter and setter for the field? Could you please paste remaining part of the class?

Comment: @AlexanderMakarov yes i have added

Comment: Can you try to rename getTransactionPartNew to getTransactionPartsNew (the “s” is missing in the word Parts at your method)?

Comment: @AlexanderMakarov great now it worked. But reading Null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settlers implemented wrongly, it should be (example for one setter only):

```
...

public void setTransactionPartsNew(String TransactionPartsNew) {
    this.TransactionPartsNew = TransactionPartsNew;
}
...
```

So, you have to assign value to the object’s field.

Comment: okay, my bad. Got it:) May i know how to read csv in order?. Because now values are assigning randomly

Comment: Can’t answer you immediately, so you can try to check Jackson docs; but you have date field, so you can use it to restore an order.